# SQLite query gives different results

Tags: sql, c, database, sqlite

I am developing a small application in C and I want to use SQLite to perform some queries on a database. The problem is that I am getting a weird behaviour.

If I run the same query on the same database on Firefox plugin "SQLite Manager" I get the expected result, but if I run it through the C interface in my program I get a wrong order of the resulting tuples.

You can find the database [here](https://github.com/Pyr0x1/cledex/tree/master/database) (CSV or SQLite format), while the problematic query is this one:

```
SELECT name, slot, id, species_id 
FROM type_names T, pokemon_types PT, pokemon P 
WHERE T.type_id = PT.type_id 
AND P.id = PT.pokemon_id AND T.local_language_id = 9 
AND P.identifier LIKE '%char%' 
ORDER BY P.species_id;
```

On Firefox I get the expected result:

```
+--------+------+-------+------------+
|  name  | slot |  id   | species_id |
+--------+------+-------+------------+
| Fire   |    1 |     4 |          4 |
| Fire   |    1 |     5 |          5 |
| Fire   |    1 |     6 |          6 |
| Flying |    2 |     6 |          6 |
| Fire   |    1 | 10034 |          6 |
| Dragon |    2 | 10034 |          6 |
| Fire   |    1 | 10035 |          6 |
| Flying |    2 | 10035 |          6 |
| Fire   |    1 |   390 |        390 |
+--------+------+-------+------------+
```

while in C I get this:

```
+--------+------+-------+------------+
|  name  | slot |  id   | species_id |
+--------+------+-------+------------+
| Fire   |    1 |     4 |          4 |
| Fire   |    1 |     5 |          5 |
| Flying |    2 |     6 |          6 |
| Flying |    2 | 10035 |          6 |
| Fire   |    1 |     6 |          6 |
| Fire   |    1 | 10034 |          6 |
| Fire   |    1 | 10035 |          6 |
| Dragon |    2 | 10034 |          6 |
| Fire   |    1 |   390 |        390 |
+--------+------+-------+------------+
```

I also tried with some simple code that only access the database with that query and I always get the same problem, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

// argument 1 is path to db, argument 2 is query

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
        printf("%s\t", argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;

    if( argc!=3 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s DATABASE SQL-STATEMENT\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }
    rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db);
    if( rc ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return(1);
    }
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, argv[2], callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc!=SQLITE_OK ){
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you'll need to post your code for sufficient assistance

Comment: I edited my question, trying to keep the code as simple as possible.

Comment: What is the output when you include `P.species_id` in the SELECT clause?

Comment: Edited tables including species_id.

Comment: seems like you are expecting:
SELECT name, slot, id, species_id 
FROM type_names T, pokemon_types PT, pokemon P 
WHERE T.type_id = PT.type_id 
AND P.id = PT.pokemon_id AND T.local_language_id = 9 
AND P.identifier LIKE '%char%' 
ORDER BY P.species_id, id, slot ASC;

Comment: Ye, that's right, but why is it giving two different result? Seems like the Firefox plugin automatically keeps the relative order when ordering.

Comment: could be due to different versions of software.  Logically both are accurate given your ORDER BY criterion.  To be more specific, add the desired columns to your ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are expecting:

```
SELECT name, slot, id, species_id 
FROM type_names T, pokemon_types PT, pokemon P 
WHERE T.type_id = PT.type_id 
AND P.id = PT.pokemon_id 
AND T.local_language_id = 9 
AND P.identifier LIKE '%char%' ORDER BY P.species_id, id, slot ASC;
```

Further qualify your ORDER BY to be able to replicate the results exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The entirety of your `ORDER BY` clause is `ORDER BY P.species_id`. Therefore, both outputs are 100% correct (they are both sorted with the `P.species_id` value ascending). If you want the results to be sorted by additional columns, you will need to include those columns in your `ORDER BY` clause.